# Extract just browser name from userAgent?

Tags: javascript, html, user-agent

I'm presenting a message (implemented with javascript) for users that goes along the lines of

> Your browser is too old to view my page. You are currently running:

followed by the name of the user's browser.

Unfortunately the `navigator.userAgent` usually looks like this:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
```

The only bit of that that I need to spit back is `MSIE 8.0`.

Is there a regex somewhere out there that will more or less give me a sane, dumb-person friendly sanitization of the userAgent string? That works for a high percentage of browsers out in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

To get browser name and version from userAgent, you could do:

```
function identifyBrowser() {
    var regexps = {
            'Chrome': [ /Chrome\/(\S+)/ ],
            'Firefox': [ /Firefox\/(\S+)/ ],
            'MSIE': [ /MSIE (\S+);/ ],
            'Opera': [
                /Opera\/.*?Version\/(\S+)/,
                /Opera\/(\S+)/
            ],
            'Safari': [ /Version\/(\S+).*?Safari\// ]
        },
        re, m, browser, version;

    userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    elements = 2;
    for (browser in regexps)
        while (re = regexps[browser].shift())
            if (m = userAgent.match(re)) {
                version = (m[1].match(new RegExp('[^.]+(?:\.[^.]+){0,' + --elements + '}')))[0];
                return browser + ' ' + version);
            }
}
```

Comment: Not a bad starting point... What about folks on ancient Blackberries and Nokias? What about Konqueror users, Lynx users, and Netscape users? PS3 browser users? Google TV users? I could go on...

Comment: To be fair, that's probably asking for too much. Now there is stuff like this (http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) which can get part of the way there (the bit that matches is likely to be a somewhat sane match for what I'd like to show).